# Deriving new column using list comprehension and a string series in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I am trying to derive a new column in my data frame using list comprehension (containing strings). I am not sure what am I doing wrong but couldn't figure out the mistake in my code.

I have a list as below

```
buyout_deals = ['BIMBO', 'EBO', 'IBI', 'IBO', 'MBI', 'MBO', 'Secondary buyout', 'Take Private']
```

I am trying to derive a new column in my data frame using the above list and a column called Deal_Type which contains strings separated by ','

```
Announced_Date  Deal_Nature Deal_Type
0   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Cross border,Private
1   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Buy & Build,Domestic,Private
2   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,Insolvency,Private
3   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,Private
4   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Buy & Build,Cross border,Private,T...
5   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,IBO,Private
6   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Cross border,Private,Transatlantic
7   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,MBO,Private
8   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,Exit,MBO,Private,Secondar...
9   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Cross border,Divestment,Private
```

I am trying to find for any 1 keyword in the buyout_deals list in the column Deal_Type. If it contains, the new column will appear as 'Buyout' otherwise 'Non-Buyout'.

Below is the function I have tried (and many other methods) but I am not able to get the desired result.

```py
def buyout_nonbuyout(row):
    if row['Deal_Type'] in buyout_deals:
        return 'Buyout'
    else:
        return 'Non-Buyout'

df = df.assign(Buyout_NonBuyout=df.apply(buyout_nonbuyout, axis=1))

df.head(10)
```

I am getting the following output.

[image]

The row at index 5,7 and 8 should be Buyout and not Non-Buyout since it contains at least one keyword from the buyout_deals list.

Expected Result:

[image]

Could anyone please help me with that? I have tried for loop as well but not getting the correct result. 
Thanks.

Comment: please add the expected output in the Question

Comment: I have added it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = (
    df.assign(Buyout_NonBuyout=df.Deal_Type.apply(lambda x: sum([e in(x) for e in buyout_deals])))
    .assign(Buyout_NonBuyout=df.Buyout_NonBuyout.apply(lambda x: 'Buyout' if x>0 else 'Non-Buyout'))
)


    Announced_Date  Deal_Nature         Deal_Type                               Buyout_NonBuyout
0   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Cross border,Private                    Non-Buyout
1   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Buy & Build,Domestic,Private            Non-Buyout
2   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,Insolvency,Private             Non-Buyout
3   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,Private                        Non-Buyout
4   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Buy & Build,Cross border,Private,T...   Non-Buyout
5   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,IBO,Private                    Buyout
6   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Cross border,Private,Transatlantic      Non-Buyout
7   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,MBO,Private                    Buyout
8   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Domestic,Exit,MBO,Private,Secondar...   Buyout
9   2019-05-14  Recommended Acquisition,Cross border,Divestment,Private         Non-Buyout
```

Comment: Getting TypeError:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: Hey. Got it. There were some blank rows. It works perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try something like this:

```py
def buyout_nonbuyout(row):
    deal_types = row['Deal_Type'].split(',')
    for deal_type in deal_types:
        if deal_type in buyout_deals:
            return 'Buyout'
    return 'Non-Buyout'
```

Comment: Hi @v_a. Thank you for the input. Really appreciate it. Works perfectly fine. :)